# Is there any way to list out files from Hadoop hdfs and store only the file names to the local and not the actual file itself?

Tags: file, hadoop, hdfs

Is there any way to list out files from Hadoop hdfs and store only the file names to the local?

example:

I have a file **india_20210517_20210523.csv**. I m currently copying the files from hdfs to local using copytolocal command but copying files to local is time-consuming as files are huge. All I need is the name of the files to be stored in a .txt file to perform cut operations using bash script.

Kindly help me

Comment: You can redirect output from hdfs list command, for example `hdfs dfs -ls -C hdfs/path/you/want/files/from > file_list.out`

Answer (score 1):

**The easiest way to do is to use the below command.**

```
hdfs dfs -ls /path/fileNames | awk '{print $8}' | xargs -n 1 basename > Output.txt
```

**How it works:**

```
hdfs dfs -ls : This will list all the information about the path
```

```
awk '{print $8}' : To print the 8th column of the output
```

```
xargs -n 1 basename : To get the file names alone excluding the path
```

```
> Output.txt : To store the file names to a text file
```

**Hope this answers your question.**

Comment: Recent Hadoop versions added `-C` option that prints file paths and names only, so there is no need for all this wizardry.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this programmatically, you can use [FileSystem](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html) and [FileStatus](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileStatus.html) objects from Hadoop to:

1. list the contents of your (current or another) target directory,
2. check if each of the records of this directory is either a file or another directory, and
3. write the name of each file as a new line to a file stored locally.

The code for this type of application can look like this:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.*;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;


public class Dir_ls
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        // get input directory as a command-line argument
        Path inputDir = new Path(args[0]);  

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);

        if(fs.exists(inputDir))
        {
            // list directory's contents
            FileStatus[] fileList = fs.listStatus(inputDir);

            // create file and its writer
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("output.txt"));

            // scan each record of the contents of the input directory
            for(FileStatus file : fileList)
            {
                if(!file.isDirectory()) // only take into account files
                {
                    System.out.println(file.getPath().getName());
                    pw.write(file.getPath().getName() + "\n");
                }
            }

            pw.close();
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Directory named \"" + args[0] + "\" doesn't exist.");
    }
}
```

So if we want to list the files from the root (`.`) directory of HDFS, and we have these as the contents under it (notice how we both have directories and text files):
[image]

This will be the command line output of the application:
[image]

And this will be what's written inside the `output.txt` text file stored locally:
[image]